# Compute time when data is sent and received by a FastAPI endpoint

Tags: python, api, server, network-programming, file-transfer

As per the title I'm struggling to compute the time when data is sent and received by a FastAPI endpoint. I'm not looking for the total response time but for:

```
• Time taken for the file to travel from host to server machine
• Time taken for the file to travel back from server machine to host
```

Comment: Such timings cannot be measured server side. The server does not know when how the long the network transfer took. This can only be measured on the client and if the server adds some timestamps.

Comment: Does "host" mean "client" in your case or what host are you referring to? In case of "client": the server cannot know either of that times exactly, only the client knows when the request actually starts and finishes.

Comment: On the client side (host=client my bad, where the client is a local machine) the time is measured before making the request to the API and, on the server side (EC2 AWS), I compute the time when the file reaches the API but the time set on the two machines is different and it is hard to make an inference